# MonoTouch detect if Microphone is enabled on iPhone

Tags: xamarin.ios

My app is using Microphone to record voice. How do i detect (from Monotouch code) if the Microphone from Settings (Settings- Privacy - Microphone) is enabled.

User can go to Settings and disable the Microphone. If so then i want to alert the user to enable the Microphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AVAudioSession newsession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance;

newsession.RequestRecordPermission(delegate(bool granted) {
  // if granted is true you have access, otherwise you can display
  // a message to the user asking them to enable the mic
});
```

Comment: AVAudioSession newsession=new AVAudioSession(); is obsolete in latest iOS version.